matplotlib not working on Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to test my matplotlib by a simple code like:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
plt.show()

but when I run this code in Terminal by Python3 test.py nothing happens. Terminal freezes and I need to press Ctrl+z.
I used sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib to install the library, and it installed successfully.
Append:
Thank you people for your help. Actually none of the responses could help so, I decided to use Spyder instead. And it worked great there. Although I couldn't find the source of issue, but I am happy that my code works in Spyder and I can continue my work.

Is your system using X11 or Wayland? What is the value of the DISPLAY environment variable?

Your code works for me in Kubuntu 24.04. I am using X11

@steeldriver I got "wayland-0" by typing echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY command. also, the display variable is :99.0

... so the issue may be related to Wayland - I'm just not sure how. It may be helpful to check what backend is being used i.e. print(matplotlib.get_backend()) - see for example matplotlib: Debugging the figure windows not showing

Here is the output that I got from running your code in Spyder IDE which can be installed with sudo apt install spyder in Ubuntu 24.04. This shows that there's nothing wrong with your Python code.

In my Ubuntu 24.04 the ipython3 command starts an enhanced interactive Python 3 shell which produces similar output, not surprisingly because Spyder has the python3-ipython package as a dependency.
When you try to run run the same code in the terminal nothing happens, whether you try to run it from the python3 prompt or from the ipython3 prompt. From this I conclude that there's something wrong with your terminal. Maybe it wouldn't freeze if you ran the same code in xterm (sudo apt install xterm). It's worth a try.

About the python3 command, you are right. it was a typo. Also, the code block is like this: "In [3]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
In [4]: plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
Out[4]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7c8bb77db020>]
In [5]: plt.show
Out[5]: <function matplotlib.pyplot.show(*, block=None)>
"

right, sorry! I copy pasted your code block and pressed Enter, BUT nothing happens. I have to Ctrl+Z each time I run the code. And by the way, I switched to X11 before running the code

I just wanted to try X11, as well. I changed it again to Wayland, started ipython3, pasted your code block and pressed ENTER. nothing happens, though! I am getting no response from the Terminal.

but it doesn't help again. I mean neither ordinary python3 nor ipython3 works. What could be the problem for such a simple code? this way, I cannot move on to use matplotlib in my codes!

In your first comment everything was working properly except you made an error instead of typing plt.show() you typed plt.show. Now you say it doesn't work at all. According to you now nothing works in your computer. If so, you could create a Python virtual environment  by following the instructions in this answer and install matplotlib with pip install matplotlib in the virtual environment. If you can do this then you know that the code works. Now go back to your real environment, type python3 to get a prompt, and check if print('Hello world!') works.

The same happens for me. The reason might be ipython in terminal can't find graphical widget anymore.
One of the solution is to use plotly, which can open the figure in browser anyway.
pip install plotly
plotly is at least comparable to matplotlib, it's also pre-installed in Google colab.
